# I have used /n code in my string and want to start the next word in a new column from the top row

Tags: java

I have a string representing the letter A in this way A
                                                    A A A
                                                   A     A.
And another string representing the letter B BBBB
                                             B  B
                                             BBBB
                                             B  B
                                             BBBB 
When i try to print A and B together.The letter B prints from the bottom of A and not in a new column.

```
        String A = "        A\n" +
                  "     A   A\n" +
                  "    A      A\n" +
                  "   A A A A \n" +
                  "  A           A\n" +
                  " A             A\n" +
                  "A               A");

    String B = "B B B B B\n" +
               "B       B\n" +
               "B       B\n" +
               "B B B B B\n" +
               "B       B\n" +
               "B B B B B");
```

output is like this          A
                           A   A
                          A      A
                         A A A A A
                        A         A
                       A            A
                      A              A   B B B B B
                                         B       B
                                         B       B
                                         B B B B B
                                         B       B
                                         B B B B B

I want the output to be  like this

```
                         A          B B B B B
                       A   A        B       B
                      A      A      B       B
                     A A A A A      B B B B B
                    A         A     B       B
                   A            A   B      B
                  A              A  B BB B B
```

Comment: Perhaps if you used separate Strings for each line of your character, and used `print` and `println` you will be able to achieve the affect you wish

Comment: You have not used `/n` anywhere. This code cannot possibly produce this output.

Comment: if you have two String objects you cannot print A and B as Adjacent letters as you have \n.

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] A = { 
                "      A       ",
                "     A A      ",
                "    A   A     ",
                "   A A A A    ",
                "  A       A   ",
                " A         A  ",
                "A           A "
        };

String[] B = {
    "B B B B B ",
    "B       B ",
    "B       B ",
    "B B B B B ",
    "B       B ",
    "B       B ",
    "B B B B B "
};

for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    System.out.print(A[i]);
    System.out.println(B[i]);
}
```

And the output:

```
      A       B B B B B 
     A A      B       B 
    A   A     B       B 
   A A A A    B B B B B 
  A       A   B       B 
 A         A  B       B 
A           A B B B B B
```